# Unable to change nav-bar dropdown styles

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am attempting to change my nav-bar dropdown background color to black. I am also trying to make the dropdown options be the width of the screen.

For some reason I am completely unable to change the dropdown background from anything other than transparent. I tried the code below but it did nothing at all.

```
/*-- change navbar dropdown color --*/
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a,.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #3344ff;
    color:#ffffff;
  }
```

Here is my code:

```
    .navbar-inverse {
        background: #F8F9FA;
        border: none;
        color: black;
        height: 7em;


    }

    .navbar-inverse a{
        color: #7B53C1!important;
    }

    .navbar-toggle {
      border: none;
      background: transparent !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle:hover {
      background: transparent !important;

    }
    .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
      width: 25px;
      height: 3px;
      transition: all 0.2s;
      background: black !important;
      margin-top: 25px;
    }
    .navbar-toggle .top-bar {
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      transform-origin: 10% 10%;
    }
    .navbar-toggle .middle-bar {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    .navbar-toggle .bottom-bar {
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
      transform-origin: 10% 90%;
    }
    .navbar-toggle.collapsed .top-bar {
      transform: rotate(0);
    }
    .navbar-toggle.collapsed .middle-bar {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    .navbar-toggle.collapsed .bottom-bar {
      transform: rotate(0);
    }

HTML

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">


 <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
 </button>



        <a id='' class="header navbar-brand" href="/">
            <p id='mainTitle'>JobQuiz </p>
        <!--<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9f/Playbuzz_Logo_(2016).svg/2000px-Playbuzz_Logo_(2016).svg.png' style="width:25x;height:25px;">-->
        </a>
        </div>

        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse" data-target="#collapse1">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <!--<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>-->
        <!--<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>-->
        <!--<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>-->
      </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> 
        <li class='headerBtn'> <button  id="headerBtn">Start Quiz</button></li>
        <!--The if statemnet below along with the currentUser varriable is how we're passing the user name into the navbar-->
       <% if(!currentUser){ %>
        <li class='header'> <a href="/login"> Sign In</a></li>
        <li class='header'> <a href="/register"> Sign Up </a></li>
      <% } else{ %>
        <li> <a href ="#">Signed In As: <%= currentUser.username%> </a></li>
        <li> <a href="/logout"> Log Out </a></li>
     <%  } %>


            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: can you add some basic html to make a minimal example please?

Comment: It's under the CSS :)

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca Any idea?

Comment: Try this [fiddle](http://codepen.io/facundo_larocca/pen/jyymvp). Let me know if it is what you are looking for. I think you only need to use `background-color: red !important;` in the class you want to change.

Comment: Thanks for the help both! If I change the background-color of ".navbar-collapse" it makes both the dropdown background red when the screen is small and the full screen background red as well. Hmmm

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's specific definition of the navbar dropdown element is defined here:

```
.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu
```

so

```
.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #3344ff;
}
```

The anchor tags inside the drop down are defined here:

```
.dropdown-menu>li>a
```

so

```
.dropdown-menu>li>a {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

The [Bootstrap Theme](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/) is a good page to play around with this stuff - just open Dev Tools and start changing things.

Comment: Thanks for this info! Sadly It still did not work. I must have something overriding it in the code above I just cant seem to spot it

Comment: Start by getting rid of the `!important` declarations in your CSS. Then remove anything that doesn't work for you so the code is not littered with broken stuff. Make sure you include your CSS after Bootstrap's CSS.

Comment: Tried that. No such luck. Hmm. ".navbar-collapse" Would be the perfect solution if it didn't also change the full screen menu bar background to red. Darn

Comment: Solved it with a hack. I guess this will have to do!

 @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  
.navbar-collapse{
    background:red!important;
}
     }

Comment: You're not talking about a `.dropdown-menu` at all are you? You're talking about the mobile menu when it expands after clicking the hamburger icon? That would explain why the solution I gave above didn't work.